# Not able to start process 'Apium -p 4732' server using Robot framework

Tags: python, appium, robotframework, appium-android

Not able start appium server using Robot framework

When i try 'Appium -p 4732' in command prompt and then the below steps through Robot framework - It is sucessfully opening working

```
Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion=5.0.2    deviceName=BH9093Y5KG    appPackage=com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook    appActivity=com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.DialerEntryActivity
```

But if i try starting appium server using RF 'Start Process'. Test case is failing at 'Open Application' step
Error - [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>

```
Start Process   appium -p 4732  shell=true     alias=test
Process Should Be Running   handle=test     error_message=Process is not running
${prcid}    Get Process ID      handle=test
Log     ${prcid}
Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub    platformName=Android    platformVersion=5.0.2    deviceName=BH9093Y5KG    appPackage=com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook    appActivity=com.sonyericsson.android.socialphonebook.DialerEntryActivity
```

Comment: Have you checked the firewall that it allows incoming traffic on that port? Have you  tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Try with 127.0.0.1 instead localhost .